# How to play music that is added on both the main screen and the second screen?

Tags: java, android, layout, screen

I am new to the android world. I am developing an app that has 6 buttons on main screen and 5 buttons on the second screen. The 5 buttons on the main screen should be able to play the music when the user click on those buttons. And each buttons should be able to play different music that corresponds to the music that is located in the raw folder. The 6th button on the main screen should allow the user to go to the next screen (Second Screen). Likewise, the 5 buttons on the second screen should play the music that corresponds to the music in the raw folder. Please look at my code.. I don't know what is wrong with my code ?

My main Java code looks like the following...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{  

    public class onClickListener implements OnClickListener {       

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.playaudio.SecondActivity");
            startActivity(i);   

        }               
    }

    public class onClick {

    }

    private MediaPlayer mp;
    Button button;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSwitch);
        button.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener());
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_2);
        Button button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_3);
        Button button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_4);
        Button button5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_5);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button5.setOnClickListener(this);       
    }

    private void setOnClickListener(
            com.example.playaudio.MainActivity.onClick onClick) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    }

    public static void onClick(View v) {
        int resId;
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            resId = R.raw.a;
            break;
        case R.id.button_2:
            resId = R.raw.b;
            break;
        case R.id.button_3: 
            resId = R.raw.c;
            break;
        case R.id.button_4:
            resId = R.raw.d;
            break;
        case R.id.button_5:
            resId = R.raw.e;
            break;      
        default:
            resId = R.raw.a;
            break;
        }

        // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();

        }
        // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
        mp.start();
    }

    {
             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;

    }


    @Override

    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(null!=mp){
            mp.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Second Screen Java class

```
import com.example.playaudio.MainActivity.onClick;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.media.AudioManager;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity

{

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);




b= (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonSwitch);




b.setOnClickListener(new onClick());




setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);




Button button7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);




Button button8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);




Button button9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);




Button button10=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);




Button button11=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);




button7.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);




button8.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);




button9.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);




button10.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);




button11.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {

int resId;

switch (v.getId()) {




case R.id.button7:




    resId = R.raw.f;




    break;




case R.id.button8:




    resId = R.raw.g;




    break;




case R.id.button9:




    resId = R.raw.h;




    break;




case R.id.button10:




    resId = R.raw.i;




    break;




case R.id.button11:




    resId = R.raw.j;




    break;




default:




    resId = R.raw.a;




    break;




}




 {




     startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));




 }
```

Comment: Just copy and paste, it's not difficult at all, same as copying text. I really don't get why so many people have trouble with that.

Comment: @  Xaver Kapeller ...I tried it but its not working....

Comment: How is it possible to fail at just copying and pasting the code here? Just copy it like you would with text. Even if you can't get it formatted properly, somebody else will fix it.

Comment: Select the code and pres ctrl+k...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't prepare your mediaplayer. I leave you a code that works. I always prepare the same song. Remember change it by your music and create an "assets" folder where you can put your ".mp3" files.

```
public class MediaPlayerActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button mButton1;
private Button mButton2;
private Button mButton3;
private Button mButton4;
private Button mButton5;
private Button mButton6;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    mButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    mButton5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    mButton6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);

    mButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton3.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton4.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton5.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton6.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            playMusic("lori.mp3");
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            playMusic("lori.mp3");
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            playMusic("lori.mp3");
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            playMusic("lori.mp3");
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            playMusic("lori.mp3");
            break;
        case R.id.button6:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}

private void playMusic(String songName) {
    if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

    try {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.reset();
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd(songName);
        mPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

I hope it works for you. Remember mark the answer as correct if this code works for you. Thanks!

Comment: Do I have to add  all of my mp3's into assests folder ?

Comment: Yes, you could put all your songs there.

Comment: @ Juan .... how would u suggest connecting the main screen to the second screen...I mean what code should I put on main screen button  number 6. So that when the user clicks on 6th button of the main screen.. It should show user the second screen which also have 5 buttons...

Comment: With this code, you go to the next activity: `code` Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent); `code`

Comment: In the next activity, you can repeat the code, using only five buttons. Remember that, if your MediaPlayer is playing a song when you switch between activities, it won't stop until the song finish. You will need a service (more efficient) or a singleton in order to work with the same instance of mediaplayer.